# Which is the api call for retrieving the events of a policy in Google Stackdriver?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

My problem is that I cannot find the api call of the Google Stackdriver for get the events/alerts of a policy I have applied. Does anyone know something relevant with the Stackdriver API ?

Comment: show more information about your problem, the code that you are using the version of the API. even the researche that you have done

Comment: Please describe more in depth what you're using and what you're trying to accomplish. This question is too broad/general in nature.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you are trying to "pull" alerts (policy violations) from the stackdriver monitoring. But stackdriver actually follow the "push" model - you specify a `NotificationChannel` (email, sms, webhook, etc) and then when violation happens, Stackdriver will notify you. For programmatic handling - your notification channel should be a `webhook` (a url to an endpoint owned by you, which will get some JSON payload sent each time when _event_ happens).